# How to increase the length and height of a three.js cuboid on mousemove

Tags: three.js

My code is:

```
// HEIGHT = height of the canvas area

function OnMouseMove(event) {
  xx = event.clientX ;  
  yy = event.clientY ;

  removeCuboid();  //each time I remove the cuboid
  addCuboid(xx ,HEIGHT - yy,breadth);

 /* addCuboid creates a three.js cuboid:
 new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(len,height,breadth) *.
```

}

This is working up to some extent only. The height and length of cuboid doesn't increase after a point, even though I drag my mouse to the extreme corner of my canvas area.

Comment: what is a 'cuboid'? Why remove and create another instead of using scale?

Comment: There is a red sphere at one corner of the cuboid (three.js object) and on dragging that red sphere the cuboid's size should increase/decrease accordingly depending on the mouse movement along the X and Y axis.

Comment: Scaling is far easier but i am unable to implement it on mouse move! how to do?

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see exactly how you have implemented it. [HERE is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne7gjdnq/2/) to get you started.

Comment: here is the demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/isha1388/t8o2u2ur/3/

Comment: How to use scaling in this??